# jQuery-mobile changePage with a modal

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just want to use changePage but to have a modal window instead of fullscreen page.

For the moment, I create my own modal box, but jQM doesn't style it probably because it's not a data-role=page.

Is there a solution without adding a plugin ?

Thanks.

Comment: If I can tweak it (hide all autogenerated buttons), yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to insist on changePage instead of just using a link?  There is a similar SO question out there (sorry no link).  You can accomplish this by using the changePage method and setting the role to dialog. If you want the calling page to still be visible in the background then you will need to do three things when the pageLoad event fires. 1) show the previous page (calling page), which automatically gets hidden on the changePage event.  2) set opacity or something on all other divs to give it a modal effect. 3) set dialog overlay to be transparent so you can see the previous pages.
The easiest way to accomplish the third is to use the overlay theme aspect (as jqm 1.0) and set it to be transparent in your style sheet.

Comment: Finally, I made my own modal : jQuery mobile isn't flexible enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try to change the target page data-role as `dialog` and invoke method `changePage` with options `{role: 'dialog'}`.

Check it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiddYu619/wWjM8/).